# dont change iframe source when click on F5(refresh)

Tags: html, iframe

i have an iframe that supposed to show me the pages according to the links.

the iframe code is :

```
<iframe width=940px onload=reSize() src="src/HEB/registerHEB.html" id="ifrm" name="iframe_main" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

i want to do that when i click on link such as this one

```
<a href="html/guides.html" target="iframe_main">
```

it will open the page in the iframe, but when i click F5 (refresh) it won't load the original src of the iframe, but the last link ive clicked.

Thank you very much.

Comment: if there a way to solve it why not. i tried to make a javascript function that will change the src of the iframe. but when i refresh the page its still return the original src.

Answer (score 0):

use this script after iframe same as:

```
<iframe src="src/HEB/registerHEB.html" id="ifrm" ......></iframe>
<script>
document.getElementById("ifrm").src = 'src/HEB/registerHEB.html'; 
</script>
```